# Laravel pass events dates to view then show in div with matching date

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

GoodAfternoon Stack,

Im trying to reach this goal: 
   Pass events table to view and math them with corresponding div of same date. The problem I'm having is:

```
Class 'CalendarEvents' not found
```

I passed all the calenderEvents to the view. How do I use that in the @if statement below? I create the date variable in the for loop in the view. First, I tried pushing this into the array in the controller, but I kept receiving an exceed memory error. Is there a better method than what I have? Im trying to learn to do things the right way. Thanks!

Here is what I have:

**HTML:**

```
        <div class = "box-content">
        @foreach($years as $key1 => $year)
          <h1>{{$key1}}</h1>
            @foreach($year['months'] as $key2 => $month)
                    <p>{{$month['label']}}</p>
                    @for($i=1; $i<$month['day_count']+1; $i++ )
                        <?php $date = $key1.'-'.$key2.'-'.$i ?>
                        <p>{{$i}}</p>
                    @if(CalendarEvents::whereDate($date)->count() > 0) ----->//Error line here//
                            <p>{{$date}}</p>
                    @endif
                    @endfor
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
    </div>
```

In my controller I have:

```
        $year = date("Y",time());
        $month = date("m",time());

        $dayLabels = ['01' => 'January' , '02' => "Feburary", '03' => "March", '04' => "April", '05' => "May", '06' => "June", '07' => "July", '08' => "August", '09' => "September", "10" => "October", '11' => "November", '12' =>"December"];

        $year_count = [$year];
        $years=[];

        for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
            array_push($year_count, ++$year);
        }

        foreach($year_count as $year){
            $years[$year]= array();
            foreach($dayLabels as $key => $label){
                $firstDayOfTheWeek = date('N',strtotime($year.'-'.$key.'-01'));
                $month_label = date('F', strtotime("2000-$key-01"));
                $day_count = $this->_daysInMonth($key,$year);
                $dayLabels[$key] = ['label' => $month_label, 'first_day' => $firstDayOfTheWeek, 'day_count' => $day_count];
            }
            $years[$year]=['months'=>$dayLabels];
        }
$events = CalenderEvents::all();    
return view('user', compact('years', 'events'));
```

Comment: you need to use namespace in view page for CalendarEvents class when you give a if condition

Comment: Thanks, can you explain a little more and how to do that?

Comment: To add namespace, use the entire name like App\something\CalendarEvents in your view instead of just calendarEvents. The "App\something " is the value of namespace in your CalendarEvents file, the first or second line probably

Comment: Thanks again. @if(App\CalendarEvents::whereDate($date)->count() > 0) is what you guys mean? I tried this and App\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model\CallenderEvents::whereDate...; but still same result.